# Symfony 5: ldap authentication with custom user entity

Tags: symfony, ldap, symfony5

I want to implement the following authentication scenario in symfony 5:

- User sends a login form with username and password, authentication is processed against an LDAP server

  - if authentication against the LDAP server is successful :

    - if there is an instance of my `App\Entity\User` that as the same username as the ldap matching entry, refresh some of its attributes from the ldap server and return this entity
    - if there is no instance create a new instance of my `App\Entity\User` and return it

I have implemented a guard authenticator which authenticates well against the LDAP server but it's returning me an instance of `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUser` and I don't know how to use this object to make relation with others entities!

For instance, let's say I have a `Car` entity with an `owner` property that must be a reference to an user.

How can I manage that ?

Here is the code of my `security.yaml` file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: "%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%"
                search_dn: "%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%"
                search_password: "%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%"
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid
                extra_fields: ['mail']
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: my_ldap
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LdapFormAuthenticator
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a good working solution.
The missing piece was a [custom user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider).
This user provider has the responsibility to authenticate user against ldap and to return the matching `App\Entity\User` entity. This is done in `getUserEntityCheckedFromLdap` method of `LdapUserProvider` class.

If there is no instance of `App\Entity\User` saved in the database, the custom user provider will instantiate one and persist it. This is the `first user connection` use case.

[Full code is available in this public github repository](https://github.com/benIT/symfony5-ldap).

You will find below, the detailed steps I follow to make the ldap connection work.

So, let's declare the custom user provider in `security.yaml`.

`security.yaml`:

```
    providers:
        ldap_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\LdapUserProvider
```

Now, configure it as a service, to pass some ldap usefull string arguments in `services.yaml`.
Note since we are going to autowire the `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap` service, let's add this service configuration too:
`services.yaml`:

```
#see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html
  Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
  Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
      -   host: ldap
          port: 389
#          encryption: tls
          options:
            protocol_version: 3
            referrals: false

  App\Security\LdapUserProvider:
    arguments:
      $ldapBaseDn: '%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%'
      $ldapSearchDn: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%'
      $ldapSearchPassword: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%'
      $ldapSearchDnString:  '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN_STRING)%'
```

Note the arguments of the `App\Security\LdapUserProvider` come from env vars.

`.env`:

```
LDAP_URL=ldap://ldap:389
LDAP_BASE_DN=dc=mycorp,dc=com
LDAP_SEARCH_DN=cn=admin,dc=mycorp,dc=com
LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD=s3cr3tpassw0rd
LDAP_SEARCH_DN_STRING='uid=%s,ou=People,dc=mycorp,dc=com'
```

Implement the custom user provider :
`App\Security\LdapUserProvider`:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Security;

    use App\Entity\User;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;
    use Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

    class LdapUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var Ldap
         */
        private $ldap;
        /**
         * @var EntityManager
         */
        private $entityManager;
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $ldapSearchDn;
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $ldapSearchPassword;
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $ldapBaseDn;
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $ldapSearchDnString;


        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Ldap $ldap, string $ldapSearchDn, string $ldapSearchPassword, string $ldapBaseDn, string $ldapSearchDnString)
        {
        $this->ldap = $ldap;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->ldapSearchDn = $ldapSearchDn;
        $this->ldapSearchPassword = $ldapSearchPassword;
        $this->ldapBaseDn = $ldapBaseDn;
        $this->ldapSearchDnString = $ldapSearchDnString;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $username
         * @return UserInterface|void
         * @see getUserEntityCheckedFromLdap(string $username, string $password)
         */
        public function loadUserByUsername($username)
        {
        // must be present because UserProviders must implement UserProviderInterface
        }

        /**
         * search user against ldap and returns the matching App\Entity\User. The $user entity will be created if not exists.
         * @param string $username
         * @param string $password
         * @return User|object|null
         */
        public function getUserEntityCheckedFromLdap(string $username, string $password)
        {
        $this->ldap->bind(sprintf($this->ldapSearchDnString, $username), $password);
        $username = $this->ldap->escape($username, '', LdapInterface::ESCAPE_FILTER);
        $search = $this->ldap->query($this->ldapBaseDn, 'uid=' . $username);
        $entries = $search->execute();
        $count = count($entries);
        if (!$count) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
        }
        if ($count > 1) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('More than one user found');
        }
        $ldapEntry = $entries[0];
        $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App\Entity\User');
        if (!$user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['userName' => $username])) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setUserName($username);
            $user->setEmail($ldapEntry->getAttribute('mail')[0]);
            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
        return $user;
        }

        /**
         * Refreshes the user after being reloaded from the session.
         *
         * When a user is logged in, at the beginning of each request, the
         * User object is loaded from the session and then this method is
         * called. Your job is to make sure the user's data is still fresh by,
         * for example, re-querying for fresh User data.
         *
         * If your firewall is "stateless: true" (for a pure API), this
         * method is not called.
         *
         * @return UserInterface
         */
        public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
        {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }
        return $user;

        // Return a User object after making sure its data is "fresh".
        // Or throw a UsernameNotFoundException if the user no longer exists.
        throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in refreshUser() inside ' . __FILE__);
        }

        /**
         * Tells Symfony to use this provider for this User class.
         */
        public function supportsClass($class)
        {
        return User::class === $class || is_subclass_of($class, User::class);
        }
    }
```

Configure the firewall to use our custom user provider:

`security.yaml`

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: ldap_user_provider
        logout:
            path:   app_logout
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LdapFormAuthenticator
```

Write an authentication guard:

`App\SecurityLdapFormAuthenticator`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LdapFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $urlGenerator;

    private $csrfTokenManager;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }


    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route') && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }


    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );
        return $credentials;
    }


    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }
        $user = $userProvider->getUserEntityCheckedFromLdap($credentials['username'], $credentials['password']);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }
        return $user;
    }


    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        //in this scenario, this method is by-passed since user authentication need to be managed before in getUser method.
        return true;
    }


    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'connected!');
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

My user entity looks like this:

```
`App\Entity\User`: 

    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use App\Repository\UserRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
     */
    class User implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
         */
        private $email;

        /**
         * @var string The hashed password
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $password = 'password is not managed in entity but in ldap';

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $userName;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="json")
         */
        private $roles = [];


        public function getId(): ?int
        {
        return $this->id;
        }

        public function getEmail(): ?string
        {
        return $this->email;
        }

        public function setEmail(string $email): self
        {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * A visual identifier that represents this user.
         *
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getUsername(): string
        {
        return (string) $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getRoles(): array
        {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
        }

        public function setRoles(array $roles): self
        {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getPassword(): string
        {
        return (string) $this->password;
        }

        public function setPassword(string $password): self
        {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getSalt()
        {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
        }

        public function setUserName(string $userName): self
        {
        $this->userName = $userName;

        return $this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm struggling with this too, but I was under the impression that this was what Symfony provided `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUserProvider` for - so we wouldn't have to implement our own version.

Comment: I too am struggling with this. I work with 5.3 and have been trying to follow the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/security/ldap.html#security-ldap-user-provider) but I don't understand how to use properly the `extra_fields` attribute. I can't find much info on it. I'm not confortable with OP's solution as guard authentication seems to be deprecated since 5.3

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 6 I do like this.

No extra implementation

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

providers:
    pmh_db:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username

    pmh_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            base_dn: '%base_dn%'
            search_dn: '%search_dn%'
            search_password: '%search_password%'
            default_roles: 'ROLE_USER'
            uid_key: '%uid_key%'
            extra_fields: ['email']

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        lazy: true
        pattern: ^/
        provider: pmh_db
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH }

        login_throttling:
            max_attempts: 5

        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: 'DOMAIN\{username}'
            query_string: null
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
            # by default, the feature is enabled by checking a
            # checkbox in the login form (see below), uncomment the
            # following line to always enable it.
            always_remember_me: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: '^/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/admin', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_ADMIN] }
    - { path: '^/', roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I don't understand how it can create a user in your DB, how it can link a User object instead of a LdapUser ? You don't even use your `pmh_ldap` provider.

Comment: @Delphine it's working like that for the folloing scenary... user have to be registered in the database but when login I check Ldap username/password. if you like I can post my lastest working setup

Comment: OK got it ! But the question was not that, that's why I didn't understand your answer. Author asked for creation of user in local after login check in LDAP. I fount a solution since then :)